# AWS Lambda ffmpeg python function error - [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/resizedVideo.mp4'

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, ffmpeg

I am trying to create an AWS Lambda that is triggered by S3. When a video is uploaded, I want it to downscale it.

I am using the `serverlessrepo-ffmpeg-lambda-layer-python3` layer provided on AWS's existing apps.

```
import json
import urllib.parse
import boto3
import os, zipfile
import tempfile
import subprocess
import shlex

s3 = boto3.client('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print("Received event: " + json.dumps(event, indent=2))

    s3_source_bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    s3_source_key = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']

    s3_source_basename = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(s3_source_key))[0]
    s3_destination_filename = s3_source_basename + "-resized.mp4"
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
    
    s3.download_file(s3_source_bucket, s3_source_key, '/tmp/video.mp4')
    
    video = '/tmp/video.mp4'
    resizedVideo = '/tmp/resizedVideo.mp4'
    os.system(f'"/opt/bin/ffmpeg -i {str(video)} -vf scale=-1:720 {str(resizedVideo)}')
    
    response = s3.upload_file(resizedVideo, s3_source_bucket, f"resizedListings/{s3_destination_filename}")
    return {
      "success": True
    }
```

I get the following error:

`[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/resizedVideo.mp4'`

Comment: What do the logs for calling this show you?   Probably `os.system(f'"/opt/bin/ffmpeg` should be `os.system(f'/opt/bin/ffmpeg`

Comment: Wow, you fixed it! Thank you. The new file is written to my S3 bucket into another folder. Now onto the next problem... why is the file 0 bytes?! :'(

Comment: You fixed my original problem though. so thank you, feel free to add and answer and i'll accept it

Comment: `{str(video)}` is unnecessary because `video` is already a string. Use `{video}`.

Comment: Also, ideally you should decode the S3 object key. See Python example [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html).

Comment: Thank you @jarmod you and Anon have both helped solve my problem. Videos now automatically resize to 720 and 360 height. Awesome.